# can i custom rendered content from API?

Tags: css, custom-content

I'm trying to customize a table that comes from posts. I'm making the request through the wp-json/wp/v2/posts/id API. Within this publication I have a table that I would like to customize. Can someone help me?
The image shows how it comming from WP. I'd like to custom it, adding border, colors, margin..
i've tried to add table, td and th in my css file.. did not work

[image: can't custom table]

thank you!

Comment: You should put some css in your theme/child-theme stylesheet or in the customizer.

Comment: already tried it, but couldn't customize my table. what a add at my code was:

table {
  font-size: 30px!important;
  color: red;
}

Trying to change something, but nothing happened